# Allow admin to activate or deactivate users-- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin, activation

I've managed to make an app that works only to sign up and to log in. Currently, I'm allowing users by mail account activation (following this tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset and by 'rails generate controller AccountActivations --no-test-framework') but I want admin to be able to activate or deactivate users. In my users model, I managed to define two methods:

```
def activate_account!   
  update_attribute :is_active, true 
end

def deactivate_account!   
  update_attribute :is_active, false 
end
```

And on my users partial view, I managed to

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %> 
  <%= button_to "Deactivate", user, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> 
<% end %>
```

My routes look like this:

```
get 'password_resets/new'
get 'password_resets/edit'
root             'static_pages#home'
get 'help'    = 'static_pages#help'
get 'about'   = 'static_pages#about'
get 'contact' = 'static_pages#contact'
get 'signup'  = 'users#new'
get    'login'   = 'sessions#new'
post   'login'   = 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout'  = 'sessions#destroy'
resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

The problem is that I don't know how to proceed. I don't want to use either Devise or CanCan because, as a beginner, I want to know how to do it manually. Please help me in implementing activation and deactivation of users from application (Admin can only this).

[Here is my app.](https://obscure-retreat-6564.herokuapp.com/signup)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, first read [chapters 9 and 10](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#cha-updating_showing_and_deleting_users) of Hartl's Rails Tutorial.

Add and admin flag to users

```
rails g migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean
```

This will give you `.admin?` "for free" as Active Record will generate this method.

And I'd write your button like this

```
<% if current_user.admin? && @user != current_user %> <%=link_to "deactivate", deactivate_path(user_id: @user), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> <% end %>
```

Then in your controller:

```
def deactivate
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  if current_user.admin?
    user.deactivate_account!
    redirect_to users_path 
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

And in your routes, something like:

```
post "/deactivate", to: "users#deactivate"
```

Anyway, I'm giving you a rough guide, but do read Hartl's tutorial, as your use case is almost covered there.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Chase! Thanks so much.. Already, read those chapters.. they were great! Still have problems though. Nevertheless, I think it is a routing problem as the app now has the button for deactivating and the confirmation, but fails to complete the action. I also changed the controller to: `def deactivate
    User.find(params[:id]).deactivate
    flash[:success] = "User deactivated"
    redirect_to users_url
  end` and defined first `before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy, :deactivate]`. What could be wrong?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? If you can add your error, I'll edit my response to address it.

Comment: On the web page: `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`. On the logs: `...lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout`

Comment: Routing error indeed. Could you share your updated route and link?

Comment: Pasted route here: http://pastie.org/10340895. Not sure about link: config/routes.rb? Or the app's link? I still haven't merge or push it.

Comment: Ok, now what does the link/button look like?

Comment: See it here: http://s28.postimg.org/n12u6j0gd/Captura_de_pantalla_2015_08_10_a_la_s_0_17_00.png. The code is here: http://pastie.org/10340900 Maybe if you need them: http://s18.postimg.org/s8heagfah/Captura_de_pantalla_2015_08_10_a_la_s_0_17_13.png, http://s30.postimg.org/pk2rvihhd/Captura_de_pantalla_2015_08_10_a_la_s_0_17_23.png

Comment: I edited the link in my answer and tested it on my machine. This should work now.

Comment: No luck yet. Now I have this error: 'Couldn't find User with 'id'='. Thanks, though! :)

Comment: Check what you're passing in to User.find(), and check what is in params. You should be able to get it from here.

Answer (score 2):

According to Rails convention:

`PUT is used for updating an existing resource`

`POST is used for creating a new resource`

So, you should make this a `PUT` request rather than `POST` as it is updating the `user` record.

You should define your route like this:

```
put 'deactivate/:id(.:format)', :to => 'users#deactivate', :as => :deactivate_user
```

And, in your `user` partial:

```
<%=link_to "Deactivate", deactivate_user_path(user), method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%>
```

Everything should work now with your existing code.